# Classificar um vetor de textos usando expressões regulares usando R

Tags: r, regex

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte vetor de textos (`character`):

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:3, 
                txt=c('Um gato e um cachorro', 
                      'Cachorros jogam bola usando alpargatas', 
                      'gatinhos cospem bolas de pêlos'), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar uma coluna booleana em `d` que fosse `TRUE` **se o texto contêm (gato ou cachorro) e bola**.

Uma alternativa que eu teria seria criar uma coluna para cada uma dessas expressões, e depois fazer uma operação lógica. Usando os pacotes `dplyr` e `stringr` (observe que eu não sei muito de regex e portanto elas ficaram grandes, feias e ineficientes, mas isso não é importante):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)    
d %>%
  mutate(gato=str_detect(txt, ignore.case('^gat[aio]| gat[aio]')),
         cachorro=str_detect(txt, ignore.case('cachor')),
         bola=str_detect(txt, ignore.case('bola')),
         result=(gato | cachorro) & bola)
```

Resultado:

```
  id                                    txt  gato cachorro  bola result
1  1                  Um gato e um cachorro  TRUE     TRUE FALSE  FALSE
2  2 Cachorros jogam bola usando alpargatas FALSE     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE
3  3         gatinhos cospem bolas de pêlos  TRUE    FALSE  TRUE   TRUE
```

Agora, generalizando a pergunta: digamos que eu tenha um conjunto de `p` expressões regulares a ser aplicado no vetor de texto de tamanho `n`, e quero criar uma coluna booleana que seja o resultado de uma operação lógica a partir da detecção dessas expressões nos textos.

**Pergunto:** existe uma maneira de resolver isso sem precisar avaliar o texto `p` vezes? Isto é, será que dá para diminuir o número de vezes que eu aplico `str_detect` no meu texto?

O motivo da pergunta é porque i) tanto meu `n` quanto meu `p` são muito grandes e ii) não queria escrever explicitamente um monte de variáveis booleanas.

Uma resposta compatível com a utilização do `dplyr` seria ótima, mas não é necessária. Agradeceria por qualquer contribuição!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JulioTrecenti, existe uma maneira sim: incluir os testes lógicos na Regex. Veja que o pipe (|) é o equivalente a uma operação OR, mas para implementar a operação AND vamos precisar do [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Outro ponto é que eu vou utilizar o grepl() ao invés do str_detect(), pois nesse caso eu simplesmente quero avaliar uma expressão regular com resposta binária, e portanto o grepl() já dá conta do recado. Suponto que o data.frame foi criado como você citou o seguinte código resolve o problema em uma linha:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(result = grepl(d$txt, pattern = '(?=.*gat[aio]|[cC]achor)(?=.*bola)', perl = T))

  id                                    txt result
1  1                  Um gato e um cachorro  FALSE
2  2 Cachorros jogam bola usando alpargatas   TRUE
3  3         gatinhos cospem bolas de pêlos   TRUE
```

Veja que o (?=alguma coisa)(?=outra coisa) diz para achar "alguma coisa" E voltar atrás achando "outra coisa". Esse alguma coisa é: alguma coisa = gato OU cachrro, sendo que o OU é representado pelo pipe. Note também a opção "perl = T" no grepl() que diz ao R para usar a regex de acordo com o perl. Sem esse recurso o lookahead não funciona.

Comment: Obrigado, @FlavioBarros! Uma coisa que eu não entendi: por quê é necessário utilizar o primeiro ?= em `(?=alguma coisa)`, se ele vai olhar para trás e não ver nada?

Comment: É que o AND assim está improvisado. No caso estamos dizendo para o regex verificar o texto duas vezes em busca do padrão.

Comment: Maravilha. Obrigado.

Comment: Outra coisa, `grepl('.*gat[aio]', 'Cachorros jogam bola usando alpargatas')` retorna `TRUE` (não quero). Por isso que eu usei o `^gat[aio]` ou ` gat[aio]`. Tem solução melhor?

Comment: @JulioTrecenti você poderia usar o \s para representar um espaço em branco antes da palavra. No R tem que colocar uma barra a mais (\\s), logo ficaria assim:   `grepl('.*\\sgat[aio]', 'Cachorros jogam bola usando alpargatas')`